# Upgrade Quota for URL Fetch calls in Google Cloud Console Project

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on, urlfetch, quota, google-cloud-console

I have a Google Sheets Add-On named FintualFinance (available in the Google Workspace Marketplace) that makes calls to an API.

An example of the code that makes the calls is:
`const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + path);`

My problem is that it the rate limit (100.000 calls/day for a Google Workspace account) for the `URL Fetch calls` is being reached every day and users get the following error in their Google Sheets:
[Error in Google Sheets Add-On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne4zt.png)

This is the error I see in my project in Google Cloud Console :
[Error in Google Cloud Console Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrNSL.png)

I have found that in Google Cloud Console "IAM & Admin" > "Quotas" I can manage the limits of the Services, but I can do this just for the API services as in the list of services it doesn't appear the option of URL Fetch Calls:
[Edit Service Quotas only shows APIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oibxn.png)

Is there any way to upgrade the URL Fetch Calls limit?

Comment: Can you rate limit the calls with a 2 second delay?

Comment: In the Cloud console you can only request more API quota, however the [Apps Scrip[t quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas) are unfortunately fixed. So you need to redesign your functionility to reduce the number of calls. If you deploy an Add-on, make sure to do it in such a way that it uses the respective user's quota for each individual user, rather than the quota of your GCP project.